# Powershellcommand for jumping to next Folder

Tags: powershell

Is there a command in Powershell to jump to the next folder? My problem is that Powershell should search a folder with several subfolders for a particular file and when it is found moves it.
Example:

`C:\Test\1\error\test.data`

This should be moved to

`C:\Test\1\data`

and then I go back with cd. . cd. .

`C:\Test\`

Here I would need a command that jumg automatically in

`C:\Test\2\error`

And here’s my problem, how do I automatically get to the next folder without specifying it. So that I insert the command into a loop?

Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Get-ChildItem` to enumerate the directories nested under `C:\Test` then use a loop to go through them one by one:

```
$targetFolders = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\test -Directory

foreach($targetFolder in $targetFolders){
  # Switch to target folder
  Push-Location -LiteralPath $targetFolder.FullName

  # Check if file is there
  if(Test-Path error\test.data){
    # If so, move it
    Move-Item error\test.data -Destination data
  }

  # Leave directory again
  Pop-Location
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But what does `Push-Location -LiteralPath $targetFolder.FullName` mean?

Comment: @lelekMaster Push-Location is for switching locations while remembering the previous location. That's why we don't need to pass any arguments to Pop-Location, it knows where we were.

Comment: @lelekMaster you're welcome. If my answer solves your problem, consider marking it "accepted" by clicking the checkmark on the left